# Efficient Data Structure to store score board

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

i unable to sortout, and i need advice in somethings.
For example:
the group of snooker players meet every month for game and they want to maintain record who won and who loss.
they already played five time: below is the result also who played and who won.

```
1st: Cobra VS DODO - Winner = Cobra
2nd: John VS DON - Winner = John
3rd: Swimmer VS Funter - Winner = Swimmer
4th: DODO VS Funter - Winner = DODO
5th: John VS Cobra - Winner = Cobra
6th: DON vs Swimmer - Winner = DON
```

So my problem is that, what data structure is the best to store these information from graphs, Hash maps, trees, linkedlist and which structure would be more efficient.

i need any graphically or visual representation like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ODjf.jpg)
thank you

Comment: Are you storing this in a database? If so, what are you using (MySQL, NoDB, Oracle?). Or are you storing in files?

Comment: actually currently i am designing its structure like tree's hashmap linkedlist.

Comment: Hmm, you showed up on my search for PHP for some reason. I don't know java enough to help you sorry

Comment: Efficiency should be the very last of your concerns. This is such a tiny amount of data that even the most complicated operation you might perform on it will run instantly regardless of how they are stored. Pick the most *reliable* kind of storage, not the most efficient.

Comment: @Nerdi.org thank you you tried to help me out

Comment: I would create a class called `SnookerGame` which holds two players and a winner then just use a regular old ArrayList to store them.

Comment: actually i want to create its data structure like tree and hashmap and i want to evaluate both. and i don't need code or SQL help at the moment.

Comment: you are all must be right. but actually need help in visual representations

Comment: i add a image example in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to think from a broader view, what all entities are involved.

From the top of my head, these are the following object(model) defintions:

```
 1. Game (game_id : id,  players : [a, b](array of player id involved), winner :a, loser :b)
 2. Players (player_id : id, name: string, games_played : int, lost : int, won: int)
```

In your services, you can maintain a hashmap of `Players` object, `<player_id, Player Object>` to be the precise hashmap definition.

Now for each `game`, find the players involved by picking from hashtable, by looking up the `id` of the player, which in your case is the player name. 
Once both the `players` have been fetched, increment `games_played` for both of them by 1. Now if player `A` has won the game, then increment `A`'s `won` count by 1 and player `B`'s `lost` count by 1.

Repeat the same for all the games. 
Now, your `Player`'s hashmap from the service can be exposed to get the queries that you desire, by each player. This way, you can always find the `games_played`, `won` and `lost` count for each player efficiently. And if you may, you can print the hashmap straight to see this for every `Player`.

Comment: your provided advice and solution is seemed almost my answered but if possible you can draw a graphically, it would be exactly what i need.
but once again you almost provided my solution.

Comment: @OCT-DEVELOPERS great! mark as correct answer if helpful. :)

Comment: but if you please explain it graphically by using paint tool it will resolved my query completely. i also want to understand it graphically like flowchart somethings